# Referencing release variables in azurepipelines.yml

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Currently i am in the process of converting my pipelines from classic over to azurepipelines.yml and im having an issue trying to find the correct syntax to reference release variables in a bash step.

The existing code in a bash task

```
namebuilder=$(RELEASE.ENVIRONMENTNAME)-$(RELEASE.RELEASEID)
```

will output the following

```
dev-2049
```

however when converted over to my new pipeline file the above code produces the the following error

```
/home/vsts/work/_temp/ac39e1d7-11bd-4c32-9b1b-1520dae11c5a.sh: line 1: RELEASE.ENVIRONMENTNAME: command not found
/home/vsts/work/_temp/ac39e1d7-11bd-4c32-9b1b-1520dae11c5a.sh: line 1: RELEASE.RELEASEID: command not found
```

[extracted from pipeline.yml]

```
- bash: |
            namebuilder=$(RELEASE.ENVIRONMENTNAME)-$(RELEASE.RELEASEID)
```

i have even created a step trying a few different approaches without much luck

```
   steps:
    - bash: |
        echo This multiline script always runs in Bash.
        echo Even on Windows machines!
        echo '$(release.environmentname)'
        echo $(release.environmentname)
        echo '$(RELEASE.ENVIRONMENTNAME)'
        echo $(RELEASE.ENVIRONMENTNAME)
```

produces

```
This multiline script always runs in Bash.
Even on Windows machines!
$(release.environmentname)

$(RELEASE.ENVIRONMENTNAME)
/home/vsts/work/_temp/260dd504-a42d-45d6-bb1b-bf1f4b015cf8.sh: line 4: release.environmentname: command not found
/home/vsts/work/_temp/260dd504-a42d-45d6-bb1b-bf1f4b015cf8.sh: line 6: RELEASE.ENVIRONMENTNAME: command not found
```

is it also possible (in a much cleaner approach) to define this as a pipeline variable and reference at a global scope like below ?

```
variables:
  namebuilder: '$(release.environmentname)-$(release.releaseid)'
stages:
 - stage: Deploy
   displayName: deploy infra
   jobs:
     - job: deploy_infra
       displayName: deploy infra
       continueOnError: true
       workspace:
        clean: outputs
       steps:
        - bash: |
            echo This multiline script always runs in Bash.
            echo Even on Windows machines!
            echo '$(namebuilder)'
```

tia

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like release.environment or any release variables are available for multi-stage pipelines. You could use the new [environment concept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops) and at that point *environment.name* would be available. I think you would likely go with `$(environment.name)-$(build.buildid)` for what you are after.

So I am not sure if the release pipelines you are converting are deploying to say an app service, or to a VM, or just using a hosted agent to publish something else? Disclaimer I have not used the Environment concept extensively yet just some reading and limited testing. Its all new!

So for deploying to VMs You can configure a [Virtual Machine resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments-virtual-machines?view=azure-devops) in an environment. This concept has a bunch of parallels with classic [deployment group agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops). You register an agent on a target machine. From there your pipeline steps can execute in that machine's context and you get a further set of environment variables.

[image]

The example pipeline below outputs any environment variables from the context the steps are running in and also outputs `$(environment.name)-$(build.buildid)`

- A normal job in a hosted pipeline

[image]

- A Deployment to an Environment

[image]

- A Deployment to an Environment with a VM resource

[image]

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  namebuilder: '$(environment.name)-$(build.buildid)'

jobs:
- job: NormalJobInHostedPipeline
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    name: EnvironmentVariables
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: 'gci env:* | sort-object name'
  - bash: |
        echo This multiline script always runs in Bash.
        echo Even on Windows machines!
        echo '$(namebuilder)'

  # track deployments on the environment
- deployment: DeploymentHostedContext
  displayName: Runs in Hosted Pool
  pool:
    vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
  # auto creates an environment if it doesn't exist
  environment: 'Dev'
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - task: PowerShell@2
          name: EnvironmentVariables
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: 'gci env:* | sort-object name'
        - bash: |
            echo This multiline script always runs in Bash.
            echo Even on Windows machines!
            echo '$(namebuilder)'

# Similar to Deployment Group Agent need to register them -stage will fail if resource does not exist
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments-virtual-machines?view=azure-devops
- deployment: DeploymentVirtualMachineContext
  displayName: Run On Virtual Machine Agent
  environment:
    name: DevVM
    resourceType: VirtualMachine
  strategy:                 
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - task: PowerShell@2
          name: EnvironmentVariables
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: 'gci env:* | sort-object name'
        - task: PowerShell@2
          name: VariableName
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: 'echo $(namebuilder)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(System.StageName)` in place of `$(Release.EnvironmentName)`, as for release Id, you'd need to use `$(Build.BuildId)`

I found that `$(Environment.Name)` doesn't work unless you're using environments. I'm not since it's still quite limited.